# How can i use method as parameter?(TimerCallback)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I want to build MyTimer class but can't get method name as parameter. It says "Cannot access non-static method 'TimerCallBack' in static context. I know it's ok if method is static but i want to use this class for both static and non-static timercallback methods. I can do that directly give method name to timer object in test class but when i try to give to MyTimer and use this parameter in timer object, it's not working. How can i solve this problem?

```
class MyTimer
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private int _period;
    private int _dueTime;

    public MyTimer(TimerCallback timerCallBack, int period = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite,
        int dueTime = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, object _state = null)
    {
        this._period = period;
        this._dueTime = dueTime;
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerCallBack, _state, dueTime, period);
    }

    public void Start(int period = 0)
    {
        if (_timer != null)
        {
            if (period != 0)
            {
                _period = period;
            }
            _timer.Change(_dueTime, _period);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Change(int dueTime, int period)
    {
        if (dueTime!= System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            _dueTime = dueTime;
        }
        if (period != System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            _period = period;
        }
        _timer.Change(_dueTime, _period);
    }

    public void Period(int period)
    {
        if (period >= 0)
        {
            _period = period;
        }
    }

    public void DueTime(int dueTime)
    {
        if (dueTime >= 0)
        {
            _dueTime = dueTime;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer = null;
    }
}

class test
{
    private MyTimer _timer = new MyTimer(TimerCallBack, 1, 0, null);

    void TimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is move the initialization of the `_timer` object into a constructor, like this:

```
class test
{
    private MyTimer _timer; // Removed field initializer.

    // Added constructor.
    internal test()
    {
        // Moved initialization of _timer into constructor.
        _timer = new MyTimer(TimerCallBack, 1, 0, null);
    }

    void TimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The error is indicating that a field initializer can't use a non-static member (in this case, your `TimerCallBack` method). Field initializers run before constructors, so there would be no way a field initializer could use an instance member (i.e. the `TimerCallBack` method) before the instance is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use TimerCallback at all!

You can define a delegate like here:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public delegate void callableMethod();
        callableMethod outsideMethod;

        public MyClass(callableMethod usersMethod)
        {
            outsideMethod = usersMethod;
        }
    }
```

And then you can call it like this somewhere in MyClass:

```
outsideMethod();
```

Comment: That is precisely what TimerCallback is - it's a delegate taking an object and returning void.  There's no real difference between your suggestion and the original poster's code at all, and this wouldn't solve their problem, which was trying to pass an instance method before an instance exists.

Comment: Ah damn it I didnt read correctly.

In that case I would say the original poster should question their architecture and why exactly theire doing it. There are often better ways when you notice youre doing something very uncommon. The latter is most of the time not needed.